# Saving flutter localization text in a separate file

Tags: flutter

im making a flutter app as an example to learn. very early on i decided to integrate internationalization to my app to learn how to do it. i wen through all the steps [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) without any problems. i saved strings in 2 languages and could access them from the `main.dart` file without problem.

after some time i realized typing the whole `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.SampleText` every time was tedious. and after i learned about dart barrel files and saving constants to separate files and just accessing them, i thought maybe i could do the something similar for my strings that are in 2 languages and access them like `AppStrings.SampleText`. so i made a separate file, imported material.dart and created a class like so

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

}
class AppStrings {
  AppStrings._();

   static String SampleText = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.SampleText;

  }
```

but i get the error that context is undefined.

is there a way to pass context from my main.dart file or not use it and get the result i want?

i tried using `AppLocalizations.current.SampleText`but i get the error `The getter 'current' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.`
im just starting to learn so there might be things ive missed so i would appreciate any help or any better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't access your localized strings like this. Prefer using an `extension` to reduce the verbosity of your code:

### Example

```dart
extension BuilContextExtensions on BuildContext {
  AppLocalizations get strings => AppLocalizations.of(this)!;
}
```

### Usage

```dart
final sampleText = context.strings.SampleText;

// If you need to access context.strings multiple times
// you can even keep the reference to it inside a variable.
final strings = context.strings;
final text1 = strings.text1;
final text2 = strings.text2;
```

Comment: would this be inside the main.dart file or can you put it in a separate file?

Comment: @MasoudGhasemi You can put the extension inside a separate file, then import it.

Comment: would i be able to do `final strings = context.strings;` in a statelesswidget like MyApp in main.dart?

Comment: @MasoudGhasemi in most widget you will have access to a `context` variable, but careful, your `AppLocalizations` instance is instantiated by the `MaterialApp` widget so it is accessible only from a descendant widget.

Comment: so if i wanted to do it i would have to wrap my entire widget tree in a widget with the context variable? what widget would you recommend?